# How to convert string datetime to UTC UNIX?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have `date` in the as `string` in the following format: `202001010000`

I am trying to convert this to UNIX format and get the result in `UTC`

I did:

```
import datetime

stime = "202001010000"

print(int(datetime.datetime.strptime(stime, "%Y%m%d%H%M").replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()))
```

and this is giving me the output in UNIX, but in `CEST` format.

With the above code I get: `1577836800` but I want the output to be `1577833200`

What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: what is `CEST format`? does your input string represent CEST time?

Comment: CEST: Central European Standard Time. I am in Germany, so I feel it is considering my local timezone

Comment: Is `202001010000` midnight on Jan 1 2020 UTC or your local timezone?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi local timezone

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't replace the timezone. `int(datetime.datetime.strptime(stime, "%Y%m%d%H%M").timestamp())` should give you the timestamp of "202001010000" in your computer's local timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting time zone to UTC when converting to datetime. But since your input represents time in Germany you want a time zone that is active there. EX:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+, can use backports.zoneinfo for older versions

stime = "202001010000"
# stime represents time in Germany so we use time zone
time_zone = ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')

# to datetime, with tz set:
dtobj = datetime.strptime(stime, "%Y%m%d%H%M").replace(tzinfo=time_zone)

# unix time
ts = dtobj.timestamp()
print(ts)
# 1577833200.0

# back to datetime, again specify time zone
dtobj = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=time_zone)
print(dtobj)
# 2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
```

Note that if the input represents the same time zone your OS is configured to use, this works correctly without setting a time zone. But I think it's better to be explicit here, to avoid confusion if you e.g. run this script on a machine configured to use another time zone.

Answer (score -2):

What you're trying to get is 7 hours behind and you cannot do that from your start date. You must push your start date back 1 day and push your hours forward 17. This code will work for you

```
import datetime

stime = "201912310000"

my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(stime, "%Y%m%d%H%M")
my_date_utc = my_date.replace(hour=17)
my_timestamp = my_date_utc.timestamp()
print(int(my_timestamp))
```

Comment: CET/CEST 7 hours behind UTC? No. And in general, that's not how you would handle a UTC offset in Python.

Comment: In addition to what MrFuppes said, when people ask a question with an example input on Stack Overflow, they are usually looking for a generalized solution. "Hardcode this into your code" is usually not an acceptable solution.